# Detect Timestamp inside file

Tags: linux, sh

I have a log file like this

```
17-06-14  Name

00:00:02  ABC 1500  0  0  0  
          DEF  0 0  0  0    
          GHI 117  0 0 0 

17-06-14  Name

00:00:07  ABC 1569  0  0  0  
          DEF  0 0  0  0    
          GHI 120  0 0 0  

17-06-14  Name

00:00:12  ABC 1571  0  0  0  
          DEF  3 0  0  0    
          GHI 115  0 0 0
```

I like to convert to like this using linux shell

```
17-06-14 00:00:02  ABC 1500  0  0  0  
17-06-14 00:00:02  DEF  0 0  0  0    
17-06-14 00:00:02  GHI 117  0 0 0  
17-06-14 00:00:07  ABC 1569  0  0  0  
17-06-14 00:00:07  DEF  0 0  0  0    
17-06-14 00:00:07  GHI 120  0 0 0   
17-06-14 00:00:12  ABC 1571  0  0  0   
17-06-14 00:00:12  DEF  1 0  0  0    
17-06-14 00:00:12  GHI 115  0 0 0
```

Some one help me with this issue

Comment: start looking at awk tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with awk:

```
awk '/^$/{next;} /Name/{a=$1;next;}/:/{b=$1;print a,b,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6; next}{print a,b,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
```